# Probability Class Question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem states:

> Suppose the GPA of a university has a mean of $2.8$ with a standard deviation
>   of $0.3$. Randomly select $45$ students. Let $X_i$ be the GPA of the $i^{th}$ student. Thus, the $X_i$’s are independent with identical distributions.

Compute the probability that the average GPA, of the $45$ selected students will be between $2.9$ and $3.1$. You may leave your solution in terms of a c.d.f.

I'm a bit stuck here and don't even know where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to proceed in a problem like this is to make an assumption about the distribution on grades in the class. Most likely they want you to assume a Gaussian (normal) distribution and they have given you the pdf and hence the cdf (in terms of an integral) for a Gaussian distribution. The mean for an i.i.d. sample of size $n$ from a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ is again a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$. Can you see how to answer the question from there?

Comment: Yes I did that. I used the Central Limit Theorem. Now would I just find the normal distrubution using the sample mean of 2.8 and sample dev of .417? or is there yet another formula?

Answer (score 0):

Well I used the Central Limit theorem to find 
the sample mean is 2.8 and sample standard deviation is .0447
NOw where do I go from here?
Can I just use the Z score as usual?

IT does assume so, I came up with .0125